# How to make a child DIV remove color transparency from a parent with 40% transparent color on an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent div with:

`background-image: url('img.jpg');
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);`

and a child div:

`width: 400px;
height: 400px;`

How to make the child DIV show a part of the parent's background-image without the black transparency?

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Y6a49hy.png');
}

.child {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.non-shadowed-div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="non-shadowed-div">
      This div shouldn't be shadowed like the rest of the square
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: create a working example ( snippet) of your problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zjq48qsx/1/ Here is my problem

Answer (score 4):

One option is to do it with box-shadow:

```css
.outer {
  background: url('https://fillmurray.com/400/200') no-repeat center;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">lalalalala</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the box shadow answer is just add a border to the inner div

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.parent {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Y6a49hy.png');

}
.non-shadowed-div {
  border: 100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);  /* 100px border on each side leaves you with a 300px box in the middle */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="non-shadowed-div">
    This div shouldn't be shadowed like the rest of the square
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate this as shown below. Parent has background image only. The child has a big border simulating the overlay of the image.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200");
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```